# do Injecting Resources into JAX-WS Services in mule stdiuo

Tags: spring, web-services, mule, javabeans

i am doing Injecting Resources into JAX-WS Services in mule stdiuo from page: [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Building+Web+Services+with+CXF#BuildingWebServiceswithCXF-CreatingaJAX-WSService)

but i heve error in xml file :

```
<spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.Jsr250BeanPostProcessor" />
```

my error is:
Required attribute id is not defined in bean

**how can resolve my error?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `id` attribute on the `spring:bean` element.

Comment: i added id but after run my proje i have error left my cod for u